# Cannot get arguments in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
import re, os
from multiprocessing import Pool

directory = r'F:\data\\' #['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt', 'e.txt']
raw_files = os.listdir(directory)

# TARGET FUNCTION
def print_result(raw_files):
    for raw_file in raw_files:
        with open(directory+raw_file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-16') as f: #FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:\\corpus_duplicated\\\\2'
            raw = f.read()
            if re.search('target', raw):
                print(raw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(raw_files[:3]) #['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
    pool = Pool(processes = 4)
    pool.map(print_result, raw_files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I want to `directory+raw_file` be `F:\data\a.txt`
but it results in `F:\data\2` that can be seen in Error msg.

I think I didn't understand about multiprocessing yet, but I cannot know why via searching.

Thank you for help. (Attatched code is reduced one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `print_result` should be changed, so that it handles only one file. You give `map` the list with files and it will chunk the items in the list and hand them in separate processes to `print_result`

```
import re, os
from multiprocessing import Pool

directory = 'F:/data/'
raw_files = os.listdir(directory)

# TARGET FUNCTION
# input to this function should be a single file
def print_result(raw_file):  
    with open(directory+raw_file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-16') as f:
        raw = f.read()
        if re.search('target', raw):
            print(raw)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(raw_files[:3]) #['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
    pool = Pool(processes = 4)
    pool.map(print_result, raw_files)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

You might have to change the forward-slashes back to back-slashes for `directory`

Comment: Oh I wasted long time in other lines. I was not thorough. Thank you!